# How to restore Mysql database on linux?

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, mysql, data-recovery

I was running a monitoring program on a raspberry pi when the os became corrupted and the pi would not longer boot.

I have a backup of `/etc/mysql`. In there is a file called `DataLog.frm`. Is there a way to rebuild the structure of the database from this file? I didn't backup `/var/lib/mysql`, which I believe is the actual data. It's lost, but if I can reconstruct the database structure, it would save some pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `mysql` startup configuration file, say `/etc/my.cnf` there would be an entry with name `datadir`
[ might vary from system to system, in your case it seems to be `/etc/mysql` check your `mysql` startup script in `/etc/init.d` if any, for the exact configuration file being used ]

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

So if your data directory, i.e `datadir` is lost, the data is gone unless you have `mysqldump` of your entire database.

By the way just having a .frm file will not be sufficient. If the tables were created using Engine `MyIsam`, then `.MYI` and `.MYD` files along with `.frm` should be there